# powershell Get-Location with short file names

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, how can `Get-Location` display short file names, in a way similar to `dir /x` in the command prompt?

In this redacted screenshot of the results of `dir /x`, it would be `PROGRA~1` and `PROGRA~2`:

```
dir /x  
. . .   
xx/xx/xxxx  xx:xx PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files   
xx/xx/xxxx  xx:xx PM    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
```

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/08/01/use-powershell-to-display-short-file-and-folder-names/

Comment: @DavidBrabant ty!

To make sure, there is no functionality within powershell core or modules for this, I must pull in cmd? If so, if you want to put down as answer, i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Why would You need the (Dos) short file names in PowerShell?

Comment: @AaronThomas I researched this a few weeks ago and couldn't find anything in PowerShell that returns short names.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755822/getting-acl-info-using-powershell-and-robocopy-due-to-pathtoolongexception/37839099#37839099

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ getting the short name is the easiest way I've found to delete files with corrupt names, e.g. with spaces at the start/end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing (as far as I've been able to find after much searching) in PowerShell that will return the short filename.

A workaround is to use a simple batch file, which will return the short filename of the long filename that is passed to it:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %~s1
```

To use in PowerShell:

```
$shortName = C:\scripts\getShortName.bat $get-location
```

Then `$shortName` will contain the short name.

Comment: What about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904822